# Python - Pandas - KeyError: "None of [Index(['questions'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python, and currently trying to write a code which will suggest answers to specific questions automatically. I have this issue, when running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Book11.csv", encoding= 'cp1252');
df.columns=["question","answers"]

df

print(df)

import re
import gensim
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopwords

def clean_sentence(sentence,stopwords=False):
    sentence = sentence.lower().strip()
    sentence = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9\s]','',sentence)

    if stopwords:
        sentence = remove_stopwords(sentence)

    return sentence

def get_cleaned_sentences (df, stopwords=False):
    sents=df[["questions"]];
    cleaned_sentences=[]

    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        #print(index.row)
        cleaned=clean_sentence(row["questions"], stopwords);
        cleaned_sentences.append(cleaned);
    return cleaned_sentences;

cleaned_sentences=get_cleaned_sentences(df, stopwords=True)
print(cleaned_sentences);
```

-when running on Colab - it works fine
-when running on local Python 3.9.1 under Windows - it works fine
-when running on Ubuntu VM, running the same code just gives me the following error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['questions'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

I have tried all the workarounds found after searching the above error , without success.

I do not understand why this works seamlessly on two environments.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the windows computer, try reading and changing the encoding to utf8:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Book11.csv", encoding= 'cp1252')

df.to_csv("Book11-utf8.csv", encoding='utf-8', index_col=None)
```

Copy the utf8 csv file to the VM.

Then on the VM machine, try to read the `Book11-utf8.csv` file with utf8:

```
df=pd.read_csv("Book11-utf8.csv", encoding= 'utf-8')
```

Comment: did this and error now changed to "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements". Many Thanks!

Comment: Ah, try the updated solution to remove the index when writing to utf8.

Comment: did that, removed the index, now back to the initial error.

Comment: does the file read? Did you check if the columns are the same for the `df`? Try `df.keys()` before running any other processes

Comment: hi there, yes file reads. it shows the output for print(df) and the output for df.keys() is: Index(['question', 'answers'], dtype='object'). what I don't understand is why this happens only on the VM, on two other environments same code runs without any problem.

Comment: `diff` the 2 python files =)